# Difference list head function time complexity

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, time-complexity, big-o, lazy-evaluation

I'm playing with Difference list data type in Haskell: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-DList.html

And I see from package description that `head` function runs in `O(n)` time.
I wonder, why it happens? From first glance it looks like `head` should work `O(1)` time in most reasonable cases. But to argue about time-complexity we should define what this `n` stands for? Is it *number of elements* or *number of lists*?

Let's expand some definitions to figure out how `head` works.

First I have `x = [1,2]` and `y = [3,4]`. Then I convert them to `DList` and obtain `x' = DList (x++)` and `y' = DList (y++)`. After that I append them:

`z = x' <> y' = DList $ \zs -> x ++ (y ++ zs)`

Now to the `head` function. It is defined as

```
-- | /O(n)/. Return the head of the dlist
head :: DList a -> a
head = list (error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist") const
```

Where list is:

```
-- | /O(n)/. List elimination for dlists
list :: b -> (a -> DList a -> b) -> DList a -> b
list nill consit dl =
  case toList dl of
    [] -> nill
    (x : xs) -> consit x (fromList xs)
```

So you can say it is obvious why `head` runs `O(n)` time: is uses `list` function which runs `O(n)` time. But let's do some equational reasoning:

```
head z
= list (error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist") const z
= case toList z of
    [] -> error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist"
    (x : xs) -> const x (fromList xs)
= case (toList $ DList $ \zs -> x ++ (y ++ zs)) of
    [] -> error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist"
    (x : xs) -> const x (fromList xs)
= case (x ++ (y ++ [])) of
    [] -> error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist"
    (x : xs) -> const x (fromList xs)
= case ((1:2:[]) ++ (y ++ [])) of
    [] -> error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist"
    (x : xs) -> const x (fromList xs)
= case (1:((2:[]) ++ (y ++ []))) of
    [] -> error "Data.DList.head: empty dlist"
    (x : xs) -> const x (fromList xs)
= (1 : ((2:[]) ++ (y ++ []))) -> const 1 (fromList (2:[]) ++ (y ++ []))
= 1
```

So it looks like `head` won't evaluate whole list to take just first element and will work in `O(1)` unless there no empty lists. Is this really true and description of function just tells about worst possible case?

Comment: If you want to figure out whether the time taken scales with the number of lists or the number of elements, why are you experimenting only with examples where those two quantities are the same? Try something like `[] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [1]` and see how that turns out.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned about this case. If some lists are empty (especially when some prefix is empty) then `head` function for Difference List becomes slower. But good old `head :: [a] -> a` function also have this problem if you pass something like `[] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [1]` to it.

Comment: Instead of converting an *existing* list to a `DList`, try building one from scratch: `head (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons3 (DL id))))`.

Comment: @Shersh If you write `x = [] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [] ++ [1]`, then the _first_ evaluation of `head x` is expensive, but further evaluations are cheap. On the other hand, if you write `x = fromList [] <> fromList [] <> fromList [] <> fromList [] <> fromList [1]`, _every_ evaluation of `head x` is expensive.

Comment: @DanielWagner ok, that seems legit. I suppose your comment with previous one about `cons` can be an answer for this question. If only someone repeat equational reasoning for those two cases... But I'm too lazy to answer my own question, though now I see where is the problem.